# How to call ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js"); in button Click event of javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Can i able to call the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js"); in the button click event of javascript or jquery

Is it Possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
 $("#buttonId").click(function(){
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js");
 });
});
```